# Does IIS 8.5 support wildcard host header binding?

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I know that IIS versions 7.5 and earlier do not support wildcard host header bindings.

Have they added it in the latest version (8.5)?  I see that it finally supports SNI and wildcard binding (*.mydomain.com) seems like it would be a related feature.

Answer (score 6):

Worth noting that IIS 10.0 **does** support wildcard host names, see: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support

Answer (score 2):

I do not think so. When trying to use *.example.com as host header IIS 8 tells me:

[image]

So a * is still forbidden as hostheader

Comment: Not when done properly with SNI.

Comment: I tried it on a host which is currently using SNI. No-go to use a wildcard host header.

Comment: Hmm, Interesting...

Answer (score 1):

Although it wasn't supported, MS did allow multiple certs to be bound to multiple sites on the same IP.  The problem was that it usually broke when requests came in.

In IIS 8.5 with the addition of SNI support, you are correct in that it will allow you to do what you are wanting to do now; that is, use a single IP (or many) and bind multiple sites with either a regular SSL or a wildcard.

See [here](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-8.htm#multiple) for how to use SNI and wildcards in IIS. **(Multiple Certificates using SNI.)**

Please note, you will have to tweak some settings, more DNS than IIS, but it will work.  [See here for how to do a workaround.](http://dirk.net/2008/05/28/wildcard-host-header-binding-and-subdomains-with-iis7/)

Comment: This is not what he's asking. He wants to do a wildcard binding. Bind `*.domain.com` to an IIS Website. Not possible.

Comment: I hadn't finished editing my answer the first time as I realized that too... thanks for the catch though...

Comment: The workaround is not very handy. You still need an IP per certificate/wildcard then. I guess what the OP tries to do is having: `*.domain1.com` as one website, and `*.domain2.com` as another website, all hosted on the same host.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but it requires slightly more work. You will need a dedicated IP address for the site.

1. Point all domains to the single IP.
2. Bind the IP to your site without any Host Name.
3. Write a simple script to inspect the URL and redirect and/or deliver content from the appropriate folder/db etc.

Comment: How about site with https (ssl)?

Comment: That's basically what a reverse proxy does, might as well use nginx.